# How to combine code listings and graphics in a complex layout using LaTeX?

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats, minipage

I have tried many things to no fruition, including tables and subfigures.

My goal is to achieve the layout below, where:

- the grayed out parts represent code listings
- and the plot rectangles represent `.pdf` graphics

This layout would preferably be a figure that can be referenced throughout the manuscript and `LaTeX` can assign a number to it. However, even a table will do. My only constraint is that I must use `\documentclass[man, a4paper, 12pt]{apa7}`, i.e., the `apa7` class, and sometimes this results in conflicts with other packages.

I would appreciate any help in understanding how such layouts can be effectively achieved using `LaTeX`.

[image]

---

**Edit.** Based on the comments below and the answer from Simon Dispa I was able to achieve what I wanted. I am leaving this code here as a reference in case others are interested in something similar.

```latex
\documentclass[man, a4paper, 12pt]{apa7}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{framed}

% Minted settings.
\setminted{fontsize=\footnotesize, baselinestretch=1.5}

% Required by `apa7'.
\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Example caption.}
    \label{fig:layout}
    \begin{framed}
        \centering
        % Left side.
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
            \textbf{Code}
            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
                # Load library.
                library(powerly)

                # Run the method.
                results <- powerly(
                    range_lower = 400,
                    range_upper = 1400,
                    samples = 20,
                    replications = 30,
                    measure = "sen",
                    measure_value = 0.6,
                    statistic = "power",
                    statistic_value = 0.8,
                    model = "ggm",
                    nodes = 10,
                    density = 0.4
                )
            \end{minted}

            \textbf{Output}
            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
                # Show summary.
                summary(results)
            \end{minted}

            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{text}
                Method run (6.98 sec):
                - converged: yes
                - iterations: 1
                - recommendation: 834
            \end{minted}
        \end{minipage}
        \quad
        % Right side.
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            \textbf{Plots}
            % Plot 1.
            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
                plot(results, step = 1)
            \end{minted}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.1cm]{example-image}

            % Plot 2.
            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
                plot(results, step = 2)
            \end{minted}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.1cm]{example-image}

            % Plot 3.
            \begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
                plot(results, step = 3)
            \end{minted}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.1cm]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{framed}
    \figurenote {Example note.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include one of your fruitless trials? Thanks.

Comment: What about captions? Does each of your images on the right get an individual caption with its own number or subcaptions? What about the code listing and the output? How are they created and will they get captions, as well? Do you also need the box and the vertical and horizontal separation lines?

Comment: @leandriis, no subcaptions are needed, only a general caption referring to the whole layout. Both the code listing and the output listing are created using `minted` (the Code section is 10 lines long; the Output section is 3 lines long). The box around the plots is not needed. All plots can be assumed to have the same aspect ratio as in the drawing. The vertical and horizontal lines are not needed either.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I will get what I tried to an MRE that compiles and post it here.

Comment: A figure environment with two side by side minipages should work. In the first minipage, place the code and the output, in the second, place the three images.

Comment: @leandriis, your suggestion helped greatly, but I am still having a hard time aligning things. Do you also have any tips in that regard? Also, I added an MRE based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Mihai: Others don't have access to the file `graphics/placeholder`, so the MWE isn't compilable. You may want to use `example` image instead. Also, how wide are the plots? Your code seems to be wider than the width of the minipage. Try with a larger width for the left minipage and a smaller width for the right minipage environment.

Comment: @leandriis, I fixed the MWE to use an example image. Thank you, I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @Mihai: I just had a look at your updated code. Images that are 12cm wide will not fit next to your code if you don't want them to protrude into the margin. Your images can't be wider than approximately 9cm.

Comment: @leandriis, indeed, the width of the image seems to be the problem now. Is there a way to allow the image to expand the full width available, instead of me manually "guessing" the correct width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the  file `./samples/longsample.tex`, from the `apa7` distribution, I added two minipages side by side: the left with the minted code and the right with 3 images.

No guessing needed  using `\fitfigure`.

[image: M]

```
%%
%% This is file `./samples/longsample.tex',
%% apa7.dtx  (with options: `longsample')
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[man]{apa7}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}% added <<<<<

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa7} Package}
\shorttitle{Sample Document}

\author{Daniel A. Weiss}
\affiliation{A University Somewhere}

\leftheader{Weiss}

\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\authornote{
   \addORCIDlink{Daniel A. Weiss}{0000-0000-0000-0000}

  Correspondence concerning this article should be addressed to Daniel A. Weiss, Department of Educational Psychology, Counseling and
  Special Education, A University Somewhere, 123 Main St., Oneonta, NY
  13820.  E-mail: daniel.weiss.led@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[2]


\section{Method}
\subsection{Participants}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Materials}
\lipsum[5]

\subsection{Design}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Procedure}
\lipsum[7-8]

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}}% added <<<<<<<<
Code

\begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
    results <- powerly(
    range_lower = 300,
    range_upper = 1500,
    samples = 30,
    replications = 20,
    measure = "sen",
    measure_value = 0.6,
    statistic = "power",
    statistic_value = 0.8,
    model = "ggm",
    nodes = 10,
    density = 0.4
    )
\end{minted}
\bigskip

Output

\begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
    summary(results)
    # Method run (6.9773 sec):
    # - converged: yes
    # - iterations: 1
    # - recommendation: 50% = 615
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
% Plot 1.
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
    plot(results, step = 1)
\end{minted}
    \label{fig:p1}
    \fitfigure{example-image}
% Plot 2.
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
    plot(results, step = 2)
\end{minted}
    \label{fig:p2}
    \fitfigure{example-image}
% Plot 3.
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{R}
    plot(results, step = 1)
\end{minted}
    \label{fig:p3}
    \fitfigure{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\subsubsection{Instrument \#1}
\lipsum[8]

\paragraph{Reliability}
\lipsum[9]       

\end{document}
```

This is the output of the same code using the class option `jou` (default)

[image: j]

Comment: your solution worked wonders. I tweaked it to achieve exactly what I wanted, thank you a lot!